# Royden Chapter 17 Exercise 12 find a positive set with positive measure

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am wondering how to find a set satisfying these conditions.

> 12. In the above example, let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable set such that $0<\nu(E)<\infty$. Find a positive set $A$ contained in $E$ for which $\nu(A)>0$.

[image]

There was a lemma given in the text[image]

which gives the existence of a set with the desired properties. However, it seems that this question would like me to give a construction of such a subset. Looking at this problem, it seems that the set $A\cap E$ from the example should suffice, however, I would need to show it has strictly positive measure and is a positive set. Is there a clever way to think about this or should I construct a set by copy pasting the proof of Hahn's Lemma?

EDIT:

With help from @NateEldredge inn the comments, I have come up with this proof

Let $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)\ge 0 \}\cap E$. Since $f$ is a measurable function and $E$ is measurable, $A$ is measurable.

To show that $A$ has positive meaure,

\begin{align*}
     \nu(A)\\
     =\nu(\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)\ge 0 \}\cap E)\\
     =\int_{\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)\ge 0 \}\cap E}fdm\\
     \ge 0 
 \end{align*}

Now assume that $\nu(\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)\ge 0 \}\cap E)=0$. Then f<0 a.e. on $E$ so $$\nu(E)=\int_{E} f d m<\int_{E} 0 d m=0$$ so $\nu(E)<0$ which contradicts that $\nu(E)>0$. Now fix some measurable subset $A' \subset A$.

Then since $A'\subset A$ $0<f$ a.e. on $A'$. Therefore,

$$v(A')=\int_{A'}fdm \ge \int_{A'}0 = 0$$

So $A$ is a positive set.

Comment: Indeed, $A \cap E$ from the example will work.  You can prove very directly that it is positive; just think about how $\nu$ is defined.  To show it has positive measure, try assuming it has measure zero and show that this contradicts $\nu(E) > 0$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Would I have to take $A\cap E$? Since I need it to be a subset of $E$

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I should have said.  I edited the comment.

Comment: @NateEldredge Could it be that we instead have to choose $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)> 0\}\cap E$ rather than $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \ge  0\}\cap E$? Then we could have 

$\nu(A\cap E)=\int_{A\cap E}f dm > \int_{A\cap E}0 dm  =0 $ to show positivity. Is there another way to show strictly positive measure using greater than or equal to version?

Comment: @NateEldredge Also, this doesnt hold if $f$ is the zero map. Then the set $A$ could have measure 0

Comment: I still think $A = \{f \ge 0\} \cap E$ will work fine, thought $\{f > 0\} \cap E$ would also work.  To your second comment: right, if $f$ is the zero function the conclusion fails, but in that case $\nu$ is the zero measure so the hypothesis $\nu(E) > 0$ couldn't have been true in the first place.  That should be a bit of a hint as to how to show $\nu(A) > 0$ with either of the two definitions.

Comment: "I am now considering the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)>0\}\cap E$ however, there is nothing stopping this set from being a set of measure zero."  Yes, there is!  Prove that if this set has measure zero then $\nu(E) \le 0$, contrary to assumption.  (And as mentioned, this proof would work just as well for $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \ge 0\} \cap E$.)  Hint: if that set had measure zero, what would that say about the function $f$?

Comment: Here is what I have now: if $\nu(\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \ge 0 \cap E \})=0$, then $f<0$ a.e. on $E$  so $\nu(E) = \int_E f dm < \int_E 0 dm = 0$ so $\nu(E) < 0$ which contradicts the assumption. Therefore, we must have that $\nu(\{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \ge 0 \cap E \})>0$ so the set is positive.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the idea.  (Just careful with terminology: what you showed in that step is that the set *has positive measure*.  Showing that it *is a positive set* is a separate property that needs a separate argument, though a very simple one.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah of course that is what I meant. Thank you so much for your help on this! If you write something as an answer I would gladly mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, to consider $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \ge 0\} \cap E$.

Showing it is a positive set should be straightforward.  To see that $\nu(A) > 0$, as you worked out in the comments, suppose to the contrary that $\nu(A) = 0$.  This means that $f < 0$ almost everywhere on $E$, so that $\nu(E) = \int f\,dm \le 0$, contradicting the assumption that $\nu(E) > 0$.